# Error generating links on branch io

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, branch.io

I am generating dynamic links from the application using Branch IO. It generates link properly but sometime theres error generating link like

> The request timed out.
>
> CFNetwork handshake failed

Is this issue from branch side?

Comment: There is no network issue from my side.

Comment: Alex from Branch here: this issue usually is caused by network trouble, often at the client end. I know you said you're not seeing anything locally, but does this persist when you test from other devices or on various different networks? Does this error show up after attempting to generate a link, or just when you're initializing a session as the app first launches?

Comment: It happens when generate a link and its not the everytime case.

Comment: How often is this occurring, roughly? Could you please try on another network and see what difference this makes?

Comment: @AlexBauer It happens 1 time in 50 time I guess. Its not a big issue for me but i will try some other network. Thanx for a quick reply

Comment: That actually doesn't sound unreasonable for an average cellular network. The Branch SDK has pretty aggressive timeouts so that we don't leave users hanging with a 'frozen' app while waiting for the server to return. If you want to override this, I believe the function you're looking for is defined [here](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/ios-branch-deep-linking/blob/fbb094b5701ec4ae036f1fdf6a2a8037c61faed7/Branch-SDK/Branch-SDK/Branch.h#L409)

Comment: @AlexBauer I will check and override the functions if required. Once again thanx for quick reply.

Comment: You're welcome! This should be a very rare situation, assuming your connection is reasonable. If you see this happening regularly, please let us know (this best option is to [submit a support ticket](http://support.branch.io)) because we will want to investigate what might be wrong on the backend

Comment: @AlexBauer Yes sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found error in my network. Due to firewall issue, some of the packets were dropped.

Tried from other network i was able to get rid of the above issue.